# How to fix low camera preview in ARCore android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-camera, augmented-reality, arcore

I am developing an image detection android app using android studio(java) and arcore .It has two class that MainActivity.java and  CustomArFragment.java . when my app run the camara preview not showing properly like something like blur or low quality . I already try to fixed it but it doesn't work .

```
public class CustomArFragment extends ArFragment {
    @Override
    protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session) {
        getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
        Config config = new Config(session);
        config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        session.configure(config);
        getArSceneView().setupSession(session);
       // config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
        if ((((MainActivity) getActivity()).setupAugmentedImagesDb(config, session))) {
            Log.d("SetupAugImgDb", "Success");
        } else {
            Log.e("SetupAugImgDb","Faliure setting up db");
        }

        //camera quality
        Size selectedSize = new Size(0, 0);
        CameraConfig selectedCameraConfig = null;
        CameraConfigFilter filter = new CameraConfigFilter(session);
        List<CameraConfig> cameraConfigsList = session.getSupportedCameraConfigs(filter);
        for (CameraConfig currentCameraConfig : cameraConfigsList) {
            Size cpuImageSize = currentCameraConfig.getImageSize();
            Size gpuTextureSize = currentCameraConfig.getTextureSize();
            Log.d("TAG", "CurrentCameraConfig CPU image size:" + cpuImageSize + " GPU texture size:" + gpuTextureSize);

            // Adapt this check to your needs
            if (gpuTextureSize.getWidth() > selectedSize.getWidth()) {
                selectedSize = gpuTextureSize;
                selectedCameraConfig = currentCameraConfig;
            }
        }

        session.setCameraConfig(selectedCameraConfig);
        session.configure(config);

        return config;
    }
}
```